# how can i link an spreadsheet to wordpress with dynamic changes?

Tags: html, database, wordpress, elementor

Basically I need to build a website for a telecom company and I need to build a map that every state is clickable and once I hover on it it will display information in a popup.
also, this information contains (ex: bandwidth {50 Mbps}) which the number is automatic changes whenever someone edits the number(also how to link my spreadsheet to the website)
Much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a Javascript snippet code.
The code should read from the datasheet line by line and update the information in each state.

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you be more spesefic cause im still new to the web world.